# Recovery after accidental `git am` and `git am --abort`

Tags: git, recovery, working-copy

Since I 'm heavily using `ap` as alias for `git add --patch`, I accidentally typed `git am` instead.  OK, I thought, I hope I can just `git am --abort`.

But to my horror, it turns out that at some point, `git am`, without *any warnings*, does a hard reset on your *uncommited and unstaged* work.  Provided that before my `ap` I'm most likely to have unstaged changes, this typo always means loss of data.

Actually it happened to me few times, but now it really hurt, since there was quite a lot of work.

For comparison, it happens to me normally that e.g. rebase or checkout bails out when I have unstaged changes.  Why would `am` be different (ignorant/destructive)?

Can I recover my *unstaged* changes after this?

Comment: Until the work is staged, there is nothing that git knows about it.  When you work on unstaged files, you really are working without a net.

Comment: @vgoff I think you might be confusing staged and tracked.  What I do is pretty normal workflow: I edit a file, wstage the change, commit the staged change.

Comment: @vgoff I have added note on "the net" to question.  However, I realized I'm using non-stable git (1.8.3.1), so in a sense I am working without net.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if they were unstaged then they were just ordinary files whose contents are outside of git's view. Unless your filesystem has some form of continuous data protection setup (git annex?) setup in it, I think you are out of luck. Possibly it's time to alias `am` to something else.

Comment: If they were outside git's view, how come he *reverted* them?

Comment: Because the old versions weren't. Revert is just 'replace the copy on the filesystem with the current saved version.'
Still, I'll tweak the wording for clarity.